# Probability that one will be mathematician and the other physicist?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

From a group of $13$ scientists which contain $5$ mathematicians and $8$ physicists, it is required to appoint a committee of two. If the selection is made without knowing the identity of the scientist, what is the probability that one will be mathematician and the other physicist?

(a)$\frac{20}{39}$ (b)$\frac{1}{4}$

(c)$\frac{7}{13}$ (d)*None of these*

**what i tried**:

From a group of $13$ scientists we have to select a committee of two
so $13\choose2$$=78$
From $5$ mathematician we can form a committee of two $5\choose2$$=10$
From 8 physicist we can form a committee of two $8\choose2$$=28$
Since we want one mathematician and one physicist in committee of two =$78-10-28$=$40$
so i guess $40$ combination of a committee with one mathematician and one physicist can be formed out $78$ combination.
Therefore the P($1$Math and $1$Physicist)=($\frac{40}{78}$)=($\frac{20}{39}$)
and hence the answer is option **a** according to me so is the answer right and  the method correct?

Comment: Yep! Or equivalently, how many committees consisting of 1 mathematician and 1 physicist are there, if there are 5 mathematicians and 8 physicists to choose from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here's another method (as now I see @Greg Martin suggests) as an alternative to your method and the answer by @Davide F. The number of all committees is $\binom{13}{2}$. The number of one physicist and one mathematician is $\binom{8}{1}\binom{5}{1}$ so
$$
\frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{13}{2}}=1-\frac{\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{13}{2}}-\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{13}{2}}=\frac{8}{13}\cdot \frac{5}{12}+\frac{5}{13}\cdot \frac{8}{12}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It's right:if you take someone at random $\frac{8}{13}$ it's a physicist and at the second pick $\frac{5}{12}$ a mathematician, in the other way $\frac{5}{13}$ a mathematician and $\frac{8}{12}$ a physicist. $$\frac{8}{13}\frac{5}{12} + \frac {5}{13} \frac{8}{12 }= \frac{20}{39}$$